# Find out what data Facebook stores about non-users and non-members

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy

Where can I see the data Facebook knows/has about me, a person who has not registered for the service?

I've never signed up for Facebook. I tried back in 2006, but was denied, and never finished the registration process. Since then, I've never tried to log in to it. Of course, 99% of my friends have Facebook, and I don't even know what information my friends have on me!

Almost every app nowadays also "integrates" with Facebook, to an extreme! I always root my Android phones and remove the built-in Facebook app as soon as I get a new phone. I never let people sign into Facebook on my phone, whether it be through the website or the app for the couple weeks I ignored it being installed.

I read [a question on Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/61412/anonymity-on-facebook-how-do-they-suggest-people-i-should-know) about how Facebook could know recommendations of friends by just a phone number. So further to that there must be a place or page where one can see the stored data Facebook has against them.

Comment: @pnuts Sorry, I must have misinterpreted the Help Center. If it needs closing, then close it

Comment: If you feel that would help keep it on topic, please [edit] it :-) Since I don't know much about Facebook (other than what's publicly available), I don't think I could word it right

Comment: There are two aspects: (1) what Facebook members can know about a non-member, and; (2) what Facebook itself collects, aggregates, and stores about non-members. The latter is how I interpreted the question. IMO, these are both valid and important privacy questions.

Comment: I think the question is on-topic, but I'm not so sure it's _answerable_. Only Facebook can really tell us, and they're not going to. That leaves us to speculate, and this is not the right site for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I read a question on Information Security about how Facebook could know recommendations of friends by just a phone number.

The answer to that question explicitly details that the more probable scenario is one in which the friends of the phone contact shared the information to Facebook.

So let's start there. Let's assume a phone number is in a contact list "123-4567"

At this point, before a friend syncs to Facebook. All this is a number, not a name, not an address.

You can state here that Facebook holds phone numbers (because Facebook users allow them to) to assist with the Suggested Friends / People you may know feature.

With you interacting with Facebook in anyway

https://www.facebook.com/legal/terms

> Special Provisions Applicable to Users Outside the United States
>
> We strive to create a global community with consistent standards for
>   everyone, but we also strive to respect local laws. The following
>   provisions apply to users and non-users who interact with Facebook
>   outside the United States:
>
> You consent to having your personal data transferred to and processed
>   in the United States.
>
> If you are located in a country embargoed by the United States, or are
>   on the U.S. Treasury Department's list of Specially Designated
>   Nationals you will not engage in commercial activities on Facebook
>   (such as advertising or payments) or operate a Platform application or
>   website. You will not use Facebook if you are prohibited from
>   receiving products, services, or software originating from the United
>   States.
>
> Certain specific terms that apply only for German users are available
>   here.
>
> Definitions
>
> By "Facebook" we mean the features and services we make available,
>   including through (a) our website at www.facebook.com and any other
>   Facebook branded or co-branded websites (including sub-domains,
>   international versions, widgets, and mobile versions); (b) our
>   Platform; (c) social plugins such as the Like button, the Share button
>   and other similar offerings and (d) other media, software (such as a
>   toolbar), devices, or networks now existing or later developed. By
>   "Platform" we mean a set of APIs and services (such as content) that
>   enable others, including application developers and website operators,
>   to retrieve data from Facebook or provide data to us. By "information"
>   we mean facts and other information about you, including actions taken
>   by users and non-users who interact with Facebook. By "content" we
>   mean anything you or other users post on Facebook that would not be
>   included in the definition of information. By "data" or "user data" or
>   "user's data" we mean any data, including a user's content or
>   information that you or third parties can retrieve from Facebook or
>   provide to Facebook through Platform. By "post" we mean post on
>   Facebook or otherwise make available by using Facebook. By "use" we
>   mean use, run, copy, publicly perform or display, distribute, modify,
>   translate, and create derivative works of. By "active registered user"
>   we mean a user who has logged into Facebook at least once in the
>   previous 30 days. By "application" we mean any application or website
>   that uses or accesses Platform, as well as anything else that receives
>   or has received data from us.  If you no longer access Platform but
>   have not deleted all data from us, the term application will apply
>   until you delete the data.

In terms of the registration specifically, since you never finished the process then the user you registered isn't validated. Why would Facebook store dirty data since 2006?

With actual requests of data use this form

https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/166828260073047